# Has someone conducted following double slit experiment?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

First create two separate observers  or control groups, controller Group A and controller Group B. They should not be aware of each other actions and are isolated from each other. The only modification required for this experiment is to put two interference receptors, one for Group A and another for Group B. Now Group A can only turn on or off photon detector near the slits without letting know Group B. I"m really curious to know what would be the outcome on both group interference receptors, will they match or be different?

Edit: Interference receptors should setup in a such way that it sends live result to both groups at different isolated control rooms. They should not be aware of each other results during live test.

Comment: I don't know if it's been done, but do you have a reason for thinking they might see different results?

Comment: If the results are different than our brain is fooling us. When photon is detected by the detector our brain expect it to behave as a matter. This might not be a good reason but just want to test it.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by “interference receptor”. A quick search didn’t get any results (except some biology stuff)

Comment: It's a interference detector/screen/back wall/detector box where final patterns are registered.

Comment: Related reading: delayed choice quantum eraser.

Comment: How would you detect a photon passing through the slit? Any detector I know would absorb the photon.

Comment: It's a detector that detects which slit the photon goes through.